# Conditional statement in getter method

Tags: conditional-statements, getter-setter

Am relatively new to java so I have no idea what the problem is. In my getter settings of this class, I'm trying to evaluate if the input is of integer 1, 2 or 3, then it will return one of the previously saved setters described here. I used the same conditional statements in the setter, but the getter tells me that my method needs to return type int. What am I doing wrong? Or should I be doing this a completely different way? lol.

```
public class AssignmentMarks {
    private String courseName;
    private int assignment1 = 0, assignment2 = 0, assignment3 = 0;


    public AssignmentMarks(String name, int mark1, int mark2, int mark3){
        //create constructor to use variables.
        this.courseName = name;
        this.assignment1 = mark1;
        this.assignment2 = mark2;
        this.assignment3 = mark3;

    }
    public void setMark(int assignmentNumber, int mark) {
        //assign value of the assignments
        if(assignmentNumber == 1) {
            mark = this.assignment1;
        }else if(assignmentNumber == 2) {
            mark = this.assignment2;
        }else if(assignmentNumber == 3){
            mark = this.assignment3;
        }

    }

    public int getMark(int assignmentNum) {
        if(assignmentNum == 1) {
            return assignment1;
        }else if (assignmentNum == 2) {
            return assignment2;
        } else if (assignmentNum == 3) {
            return assignment3;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: see answer for the getter problem.. but your setter has a bad logic too... you set mark wich is a parameter of the method , i suppose you thought  this.assignment1=mark instead mark=this.assignment1 ...

Comment: I see. So do I change it to evaluate this.assignment = mark;? I think I thought that it would evaluate such that the mark entered would be assigned to assignment in that order. If that makes sense. ie. a mark is entered, and is then saved to this.assignmentx. etc.

Comment: see edited answer for getter with Exception and the correct setter. Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int getMark(int assignmentNum) {
    if(assignmentNum == 1) {
        return assignment1;
    }else if (assignmentNum == 2) {
        return assignment2;
    } else if (assignmentNum == 3) {
        return assignment3;
    }

     // in another case       
     throw new Exception("Assignment must be 1, 2 or 3);

}
```

for setter

```
   public void setMark(int assignmentNumber, int mark) {
            //assign value of the assignments
            if(assignmentNumber == 1) {
                 // BAD mark = this.assignment1; don't set parameter is useless
                 this.assignment1=mark;     
            }else if(assignmentNumber == 2) {
                 // BAD mark = this.assignment2;
                 this.assignment2=mark;     
            }else if(assignmentNumber == 3){
                 // BAD mark = this.assignment3;
                 this.assignment3=mark;
            } 
         // in another case
         throw new Exception("Assignment must be 1, 2 or 3");
}
```

I don't remember if you must import Exception for throwing them.
if yes put `import java.lang.Exception` on top of your code.

your logic can be improved using arrays, but let's walk, and after you will running...